# comments not rendering with ajax in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am try to render my comments with ajax in my rails app...but it is not working  and the comments diplay just after I redirect the page...so the comment get created successfully but the problem is rendering comments with ajax and jquery!!!!
I have this lines in my application.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

and this require line in my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

here is my show.html.erb file under posts :

```
<div id="posts" class="transitions-enabled">
  <div class="box panel panel-default">
    <%= render 'post', post: @post %>
  </div>
</div>
```

my  _post partial:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <%= link_to image_tag(post.user.avatar.url, size: "50x50", class: "img-circle"), profile_path(post.user.user_name) %>
  <ul class="posts-shows">
    <li><strong><%= link_to post.user.user_name, profile_path(post.user.user_name)  %></strong></li>
    <li><small><%= link_to "#{time_ago_in_words(post.created_at)} ago", post_path(post), class: "time-link" %></small></li>
  </ul>
  <p class="disc-posts"><%= post.description %></p>
  <%= link_to image_tag(post.image.url(:large), class: "img-responsive img-in" ) %><br/>
  <% if post.user == current_user %>
    <div><%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post) %> | <%= link_to "delete", post, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %> </div>
  <% else %>                            
    <div><%= link_to "Repost", repost_post_path(post), method: :post, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"} if user_signed_in? %></div>                 
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="panel-footer">
  <div class="comment-form">
    <%= form_for([post, post.comments.build], remote: true) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: 'Add a comment...', class: "form-control comment_content", id: "comment_content_#{post.id}"  %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="comments" id= "comments_#{post.id}">
    <% if post.comments.present? %>
      <%= render post.comments, post: post %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

my   _comment.html.erb in comments folder:

```
<% if  comment.user_id.present? %>
  <div id="comment">
    <%= link_to image_tag(post.user.avatar.url, size: "30x30", class: "img-circle img-comments"), profile_path(comment.user.user_name) %>
    <div class="user-name">
        <%= link_to comment.user.user_name, profile_path(comment.user.user_name), class: "username-size" %>
    </div>
    <div class="comment-content">
      <%= comment.content %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and here is the create.js.erb under comments folder :

```
$('#comments_<%= @post.id %>').append("<%=j render 'comments/comment', post: @post, comment: @comment %>");
$('#comment_content_<%= @post.id %>').val('')
```

and my comments  controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post

  def index
    @comments = @post.comment.all
  end

  def new
    @comment = @post.comments.build(comments_params)
  end

  def create
    @comment = @post.comments.build(comments_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id

    if @comment.save
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to root_path }
            format.js
        end
    else
        flash[:alert] = "Check the comment form, something went horribly wrong."
        render root_path
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])

    @comment.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Comment deleted :("
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def comments_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
  end

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: You can debug this way.  In chrome - inspect > network.  Submit request and look closely at the response. You can retry the response in the console to see how the javascript runs.

Comment: I am not familiar with chrome network and console..but yeah it is good thing to learn..I will definitely check some youtube videos for that...thank you

Comment: Chrome dev tools is what your looking for: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this line is right -

```
<div class="comments" id= "comments_#{post.id}">
```

I think you need this

```
<div class="comments" id= "comments_<%= post.id %>">
```

Comment: yeah it is rendering now...but I get another problem... when I post a comment in a post in index my footer in the panel go behind the below post...but when I redirect it fix the problem...so there is still a problem with ajax...do you know any solution for this??

Comment: before all of that I want to thank you for your help ;)

Comment: It may be your css.  Chrome inspect will help here, too. You can look at elements and their style rules. There are many reasons the footer could be on top of the post.  Are you using masonry?  There may be a need to reload (see masonry's reload method if so).

Comment: Yes I am using masonry in my app....the thing is when I reload everything work good...so it is not the ajax?? To be more clear I have posts in my index page looks like pinterest...now the comments are in the footer of the post panel.... when I comment the footer go beyond the below post..something like that

Comment: Yeah - masonry needs to recalculate the size of everything.  Take a look at this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722197/jquery-masonry-and-ajax-append-items  Try and add it to `create.js.erb` and see if it's that easy